# How to render list of static images with coordinates in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am novice in OpenLayers. Have got list of images and their coordinates (in another list) extracted from  big TIFF file. Requirement is to rendered the images with coordinates to get same image as in TIFF file.

Have tried the display of static image example present in OpenLayer site and able to rendered it with single image. When I tried similarly with multiple images it is getting rendered on top of previous one.

```
var projection = new Projection({
  code: 'xkcd-image',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: extent,
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: images[0],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
      opacity: 1,
      zIndex: 1,
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: images[3],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
      opacity: 1,
      zIndex: 4,
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: images[4],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
      opacity: 1,
      zIndex: 100,
    }),
    
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: images[6],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
      opacity: 1,
      zIndex: 100,
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: images[7],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
       
      }),
      opacity: 1,
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    center: getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 8,
  }),
});
```

I am not able to find any clue how to rendered the images based on their coordinates to get the image correctly. Any suggestion (with example)? Using OpenLayers v6.

Comment: Are your image coordinates geographic or pixel coordinates? In any case you have to specify individual extent for each image in the form [minX, minY, maxX, maxY], where [minX, minY] are coordinates of lower left corner of the image and [maxX, maxY] are coordinates of the upper right corner of the image.

Comment: @TomazicM - Have the pixel coordinates. Do you have any reference example it will help.

Comment: If you have pixel coordinates, what is then not clear in my comment above. From image pixel coordinates and image width and height you can get image extent as described above.

Comment: @TomazicM - Thank you, your solution works only issue. Images of 2nd row is getting displayed on the top of first one. and 3rd row getting displayed on 2nd and so on. How to resolve it.

Comment: **Changes I made** : var imageSize = [1280, 1280]; var extent = [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]];   **In layer section change made:**  layers: [
        new ImageLayer({    source: new Static({
                url:img[0],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[1],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [1280, 0, 1280+imageSize[0], imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),

Comment: It's hard to imagine exactly what you want to achieve without seeing the picture. Please edit your question and at the picture of how you would like it to look at the end, and where borders of individual pictures will be visible.

Comment: @TomazicM - thanks for your suggestion. I am able to render it correctly. Will provide the full solution here.

Comment: @TomazicM - one question how I can create lineString above the map create in this query. Some thing similar to example  [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/line-arrows.html ]

Comment: GIS SE site has strict policy of focused questions, which means one question per question. Since this is a separate question, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a rule to your image layers creation, you could greatly shorten your code by using a loop.

Code could then look something like this (not tested, so there might be some index or coordinates calculation error, but principle holds):

```
var layers = [];
var iImg = 0;
var x;
var y = 17920;

for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = i * 1280;
    y = 17920;
    layers.push(new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url:img[iImg],
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: [x, y, x + imageSize[0], y + imageSize[1]]
      })
    }));
    iImg++;
  }
  y -= 1280;
}

var map = new Map({
  layers: layers;
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    center: getCenter(extent),
    resolution: 1,
    zoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 7
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Before posting the complete solution. **Will like to thank and give credit to @TomazicM** for his valuable suggestion. And helping me to find the solution of the above query.
apart from below code i.e. main.js, I have another imageHelper.js file where I have imported my images.

```
import './style.css';
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import TileGrid from "ol/tilegrid/TileGrid.js";
import View from "ol/View.js";
import { Projection } from "ol/proj.js";
import { Tile as TileLayer } from "ol/layer.js";
import { XYZ } from "ol/source.js";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent.js";
import imgSrc from "./imageHelper.js";
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import {Icon, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';

var img = [imgSrc.i0, imgSrc.i1, imgSrc.i2, imgSrc.i3, imgSrc.i4, imgSrc.i5, imgSrc.i6,imgSrc.i7, imgSrc.i8, imgSrc.i9,
    imgSrc.i10, imgSrc.i11, imgSrc.i12, imgSrc.i13, imgSrc.i14, imgSrc.i15, imgSrc.i16,imgSrc.i17, imgSrc.i18, imgSrc.i19,
    imgSrc.i20, imgSrc.i21, imgSrc.i22, imgSrc.i23, imgSrc.i24, imgSrc.i25, imgSrc.i26,imgSrc.i27, imgSrc.i28, imgSrc.i29,
    imgSrc.i30, imgSrc.i31, imgSrc.i32, imgSrc.i33, imgSrc.i34, imgSrc.i35, imgSrc.i36,imgSrc.i37, imgSrc.i38, imgSrc.i39,
];
 
var imageSize = [1280, 1280];
var extent = [0, 0, imageSize[0], imageSize[1]];
var projection = new Projection({
  code: "custom-image",
  units: "pixels",
  extent: extent
});



var map = new Map({
    layers: [
        
        //---
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[30],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [0, 14080, imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[31],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [1280, 14080, 1280+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[32],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [2560, 14080, 2560+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[33],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [3840, 14080, 3840+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[34],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [5120, 14080, 5120+imageSize[0],  14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[35],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [6400, 14080, 6400+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[36],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [7680, 14080, 7680+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[37],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [8960, 14080, 8960+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),

        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[38],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [10240, 14080, 10240+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[39],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [11520, 14080, 11520+imageSize[0], 14080+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        //---
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[20],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [0, 15360, imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[21],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [1280, 15360, 1280+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[22],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [2560, 15360, 2560+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[23],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [3840, 15360, 3840+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[24],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [5120, 15360, 5120+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[25],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [6400, 15360, 6400+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[26],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [7680, 15360, 7680+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[27],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [8960, 15360, 8960+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[28],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [10240, 15360, 10240+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[29],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [11520, 15360, 11520+imageSize[0], 15360+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        //--
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[10],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [0, 16640, 0+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[11],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [1280, 16640, 1280+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[12],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [2560, 16640, 2560+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[13],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [3840, 16640, 3840+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[14],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [5120, 16640, 5120+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[15],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [6400, 16640, 6400+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[16],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [7680, 16640, 7680+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[17],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [8960, 16640, 8960+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[18],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [10240, 16640, 10240+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[19],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [11520, 16640, 11520+imageSize[0], 16640+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        //--
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[0],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [0, 17920, 0+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[1],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [1280, 17920, 1280+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[2],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [2560, 17920, 2560+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[3],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [3840, 17920, 3840+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[4],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [5120, 17920, 5120+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }), 

        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[5],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [6400, 17920, 6400+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }), 
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[6],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [7680, 17920, 7680+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }), 
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[7],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [8960, 17920, 8960+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }), 
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[8],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [10240, 17920, 10240+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }), 
        new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
                url:img[9],
                projection: projection,
                imageExtent: [11520, 17920, 11520+imageSize[0], 17920+imageSize[1]]
            }),
        }),  
    ],
    target: "map",
    view: new View({
      projection: projection,
      center: getCenter(extent),
      resolution: 1,
      zoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 7
    })
  });

  map.addInteraction(
    new Draw({
      source: source,
      type: 'LineString',
    })
  );
```